# How to prevent UIToolbar from getting resized when UIImageView displays an image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uikit, uitoolbar

I am building an app that allows a user to create memes ([Udacity project: Meme Me](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bt-SoB1GgqLebcT2mtE6hglkByzlxrobR5eHFMGPcTg/pub?embedded=true)).

The interface comprises of two `UIToolbar`s (top and bottom) and a `UIImageView` that spans the space between them. The remaining UI elements are not relevant to my problem. Here is a screenshot of the app when it first launches:

[image: Meme Me app upon launching]

When an image is loaded into the `UIImageView` both toolbars get resized and become smaller in height, as shown here:

[image: Meme Me app after displaying an image]

What is causing the toolbars to resize, and more importantly, how do I prevent them from resizing?

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, remember that you can mark it as correct by ticking the √ at top left of the answer. Since I took quite some time out of my day to write it, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your toolbars could be resizing because unless you specify constraints on your UI elements (such as toolbars and `UIImageView`s), XCode interprets it in its own way and it shows you what it thinks is the best layout. We usually get around this problem by explicitly setting the following property of each UI element's to false:

```
MyUIElement.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and then specifying the element's constraints programmatically. Note that `MYUIElement` is whatever you named your UIElement.
This tells XCode that you, as the programmer, want full control over the UI Element's positioning within its view.

You can prevent the toolbar from resizing by setting a constraint on it programmatically:

```
topToolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
bottomToolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
```

Of course you would replace `topToolbar` and `bottomToolbar` with whatever you called you named your toolbars, and `50.0` with whatever value suits your use case.

This is called AutoLayout. These two lines of code should be called after your toolbars have been setup (if you are creating them programmatically).

However, the concept of programmatic UI is probably not covered in a beginner iOS development course and you are most likely building this using a storyboard, which explains why your toolbars are changing out of control!

If you have created them using the Interface Builder (i.e. in your storyboard), then you can either modify their height constraint using the code above or by playing around with the layout settings in the Interface Builder, by clicking the button below:

[image]

If you decide to set your constraint through the storyboard as above, note that you **might** be told by XCode that you need to specify even more constraints (such as the width constraint) so that your toolbar's position is not considered "ambiguous" by the compiler.